# Browser level scroll bars are completely disabled when using RootLayoutPanel in GWT 2.1.1, how do I re-enabled them?

Tags: gwt, layout, panel, gwt2

I am working with GWT 2.1.1, every time I use `RootLayoutPanel` instead of `RootPanel` in my `EntryPoint` class, the scroll bars for the browser gets completely disabled, so when my content doesn't fit on the screen there is no way to get to it.

How do I use the new `Layout` based `Panel` classes that require `RootLayoutPanel` and still get my auto-appearing and disappearing scroll bars at the Browser level.

I am **NOT** talking about putting stuff in a `ScrollPanel` I want the browser scroll bar behavior that `RootPanel` provides, but with a `RootLayoutPanel`.

How do you get a `TabLayoutPanel` to autofill the page and have the browser automatically produce scroll bars for the entire page?

I tried putting `overflow: auto;` on my `RootLayoutPanel` as suggested below, has no affect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by-design. Layout panels do not resize based on their content, they resize their content based on their own size. So, depending on what you want, either you shouldn't use layout panels, or you'd have to make panels scrollables (you can just use the `overflow` CSS property, you're not forced to use a `ScrollPanel`)

Comment: So how to you use the `TabLayoutPanel` and get the scroll bars on the Browser window?

Comment: `overflow: auto` doesn't seem to do anything, I applied it to my `RootLayoutPanel` same behavior.

Comment: Don't use RootLayoutPanel then. This means you'll have to give an explicit size to your TabLayoutPanel, which you can, for instance, compute based on the size of the window and the size of the tab's content (using which height is the greatest). Layout panels are not meant to adapt their size to their content, but the other way around. If that's not what you want, it's probably best not to use them (i.e. use TabPanel rather than TabLayoutPanel)